# Typescript: Exclude one type from union that is extended by other types in the union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a union type like this:

```
export type TileType =
      | ProductTileType
      | CustomTileType
      | DealTileType
      | LoadingTileType
```

And a React component that needs to be able to take a prop of type: `ProductTileType | CustomTileType | DealTileType`. So I declared that prop with type `Exclude<TileType, LoadingTileType>` so as not to allow that type to be used here. The only problem is that `ProductTileType` is declared like this:

```
export interface ProductTileType extends LoadingTileType { ... }
```

When I exclude `LoadingTileType` TS also wants to exclude any type that extends it. How can I avoid excluding types that extend what I want to exclude? Is there another utility type I am not aware of?

**Edit:**

`type MyType = Exclude<TileType, LoadingTileType> | ProductTileType` would be a quick workaround to solve the problem at hand (In this case ProductTileType was the only one extending LoadingTileType) But in the future there might be others types that extend `LoadingTileType`. What would be a better way to handle that?

Comment: nevermind, figured it out `type MyType = Exclude<TileType, LoadingTileType> | ProductTileType;`

Comment: Not exactly ideal since if you extend `LoadingTileType` again, you have to add the new member here as well. But if it solves your problem, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: In this case ProductTileType was the only one extending LoadingTileType. But you're right in the future there might be others. What would be a better way to handle that? I'll update the question

Comment: Does it make sense for `LoadingTileType` to be a `TileType`? caTS's answer works on a technical level, but if `LoadingTileType` is some kind of template that doesn't make sense on its own (as is `Soda` in their example), maybe you should remove it. For example, say that caTS wants to add a brand of lemonade, does it still make sense to keep `Lemonade` in `Drinks`? Maybe `Drinks` should contain `MyBrandLemonade` and a new derivative—`HomeMadeLemonade`. This way you have 2 specific kinds of `Lemonade` in `Drinks` and no generic. When requirements change, the model of the domain changes as well.

Comment: In my case LoadingTileType is both a valid interface to include in the union as well as a valid interface to be extended by another interface in the union. I know the Soda example given by @caTS wouldn't make sense in a real-world application, the theory behind it solves the problem presented by my LoadingTileType interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have some drinks:

```
interface Water { healthiness: 1000 }
interface Lemonade { healthiness: 500 }
interface Tea { healthiness: 1250 } // really it depends on what kind of tea

interface Soda { healthiness: -1000 }
interface Coke extends Soda { fizziness: 1000 }
interface DrPepper extends Soda { fizziness: 800 }
interface Pepsi extends Soda { fizziness: 750 }

type Drinks = Water | Lemonade | Tea | Soda | Coke | DrPepper | Pepsi;
```

Now, I want a type that is all the drinks, except for the extremely non-specific "Soda" drink.

While I could just exclude that and then bring back the other (more specific) sodas:

```
type NoGenericSodaBad = Exclude<Drinks, Soda> | Coke | DrPepper | Pepsi;
```

What I really need is a stricter `Exclude`:

```
type StrictExclude<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? never : T : T;
```

This type excludes `U` and only `U` (although if you pass `never` it'll for sure break some things) since each member in the union `T` must be mutually assignable to `U`. That means I can get my drinks without "Soda"!

```
type NoGenericSodaGood = StrictExclude<Drinks, Soda>;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZX3Kw)